# How to read .dat file using pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a newbie to Spark, bear my silly mistakes if there's any (Open for your suggestions :))

I have created a pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object using following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

I know that I can read a csv file using `spark.read.csv('filepath')`.

Now, I would like to read `.dat` file using that `SparkSession` object.

My `ratings.dat` file looks like:

```
1::1193::5::978300760
1::661::3::978302109
1::914::3::978301968
1::3408::4::978300275
```

My code:

```
ratings = spark.read.format('dat').load('filepath/ratings', sep='::')
```

Output:

```
An error occurred while calling o102.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Expected Output:

```
+------+-------+------+---------+
|UserID|MovieID|Rating|Timestamp|
+------+-------+------+---------+
|     1|   1193|     5|978300760|
|     1|    661|     3|978302109|
| and.........so.......on.......|
+------+-------+------+---------+
```

**Note**: My `ratings.dat` file do not contain headers and separator is `::`.

Questions:

1. How can I read `.dat` file?
2. How can I add my custom header like I mentioned in Expected output?

So, How can I achieve my expected output? Where am I committing mistakes?

I would love to read your suggestions and answers :)

Would really appreciate long and detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the csv reader with `::` as the separator, and provide a schema:

```
df = spark.read.csv('ratings.dat', sep='::', schema='UserID int, MovieID int, Rating int, Timestamp long')

df.show()
+------+-------+------+---------+
|UserID|MovieID|Rating|Timestamp|
+------+-------+------+---------+
|     1|   1193|     5|978300760|
|     1|    661|     3|978302109|
|     1|    914|     3|978301968|
|     1|   3408|     4|978300275|
+------+-------+------+---------+
```

Comment: while doing `df.show()`, I got an error `Delimiter can't contain more than one character`. So, I have created a RDD first and then converted it to the df .